# How to POST InputStream as the body of a request in Retrofit?

Tags: rest, docker, retrofit

I'm attempting to do a POST with the body being an InputStream with something like this:

```
@POST("/build")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/tar")
Response build(@Query("t") String tag,
               @Query("q") boolean quiet,
               @Query("nocache") boolean nocache,
               @Body TypedInput inputStream);
```

In this case the InputStream is from a compressed tar file.

What's the proper way to POST an InputStream?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123696/android-how-to-upload-video-in-chunks-using-okhttp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I came up with here was to use the TypeFile class:

```
TypedFile tarTypeFile = new TypedFile("application/tar", myFile);
```

and the interface (without explicitly setting the Content-Type header this time):

```
@POST("/build")
Response build(@Query("t") String tag,
               @Query("q") boolean quiet,
               @Query("nocache") boolean nocache,
               @Body TypedInput inputStream);
```

Using my own implementation of TypedInput resulted in a vague EOF exception even while I provided the length().

```
public class TarArchive implements TypedInput {

    private File file;

    public TarArchive(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String mimeType() {
        return "application/tar";
    }

    public long length() {
        return this.file.length();
    }

    public InputStream in() throws IOException {
        return new FileInputStream(this.file);
    }
}
```

Also, while troubleshooting this issue I tried using the latest Apache Http client instead of OkHttp which resulted in a "Content-Length header already present" error even though I wasn't explicitly setting that header.

Comment: Your `TypedInput` implementation didn't work for file uploads because that use-case expects a **`TypedOutput`** instead, as pointed out in [@BertHartmann's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23213768/504611). The error message might be pretty unclear though.

Answer (score 9):

You can upload inputStream using `Multipart`.

```
@Multipart
@POST("pictures")
suspend fun uploadPicture(
        @Part part: MultipartBody.Part
): NetworkPicture
```

Then in perhaps your repository class:

```
suspend fun upload(inputStream: InputStream) {
   val part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
         "pic", "myPic", RequestBody.create(
              MediaType.parse("image/*"),
              inputStream.readBytes()
          )
   )
   uploadPicture(part)
}
```

If you want to find out how to get an image Uri, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61592000/10030693

Answer (score 2):

`TypedInput` is a wrapper around an `InputStream` that has metadata such as length and content type which is used in making the request. All you need to do is provide a class that implements `TypedInput` which passed your input stream.

```
class TarFileInput implements TypedInput {
  @Override public InputStream in() {
    return /*your input stream here*/;
  }

  // other methods...
}
```

Be sure you pass the appropriate return values for `length()` and `mimeType()` based on the type of file from which you are streaming content.

You can also optionally pass it as an anonymous implementation when you are calling your `build` method.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I had issues using TypedInput. I documented my solution below for future reference.

Comment: Looks like TypedInput is no longer available, so what is the solution for inputStream ?

Comment: I'm exactly a year late for @gropapa's question, but for anyone else wondering the same thing (like me): convert the `InputStream` to a `byte[]`, which can then be used to construct a `RequestBody` for file uploads in Retrofit 2.x. See [this link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1063#issuecomment-152465826) for details.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Multipart section of http://square.github.io/retrofit/ you'll want to use TypedOutput instead of TypedInput. Following their examples for multipart uploads worked fine for me once I had implemented a TypedOutput class.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to implement `TypedOutput`

```
public class TypedStream implements TypedOutput{

    private Uri uri;

    public TypedStream(Uri uri){
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    @Override
    public String fileName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String mimeType() {
        return getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public long length() {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        Utils.copyStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), out);
    }
}
```