# java.net.SocketTimeoutException when sending video using OkhttpClient 3.2 and Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I using OkhttpClient to send a video with 15 seconds long to the server using `OkhttpClient 3.2` and `Retrofit2`,sometimes it work fine but sometimes I get the error below,which is very inconsistent.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout

Here is my code for sending the video up to server

```
private void sendVideoToServer( final String videoFilePath,final String api_key)
    {
        File videoFile = new File(videoFilePath);
        RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
        MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);

        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        okhttp3.Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                        ongoing.addHeader("authorization", api_key);
                        return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                    }
                })
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();

        VideoInterface videoInterface = retrofit.create(VideoInterface.class);
        Call<ResultObject> serverCom = videoInterface.sendVideoToServer(vFile);

        serverCom.enqueue(new Callback<ResultObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResultObject> call, retrofit2.Response<ResultObject> response) {
                ResultObject result = response.body();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(result.getSuccess())){
                    Log.d("video Result " , result.getSuccess());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResultObject> call, Throwable t) {
               Log.d("video error",t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

After reading some question,I tried to set the connection timeout to the OkhttpClient like below,but still cant solve the problem.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        okhttp3.Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                        ongoing.addHeader("authorization", api_key);
                        return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                    }
                });
builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
OkHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();
```

I totally dont know what was doing wrong in this part,somebody please give me some guidance. Tq

Comment: might be the issue with server side or request params, check with postman. your code looks fine

Comment: I checked with postman,all doing well,but in android,I test with real device,it always timeout.

Comment: have you tried the large file with the postman.

Comment: I tried with 4 minutes video video with postman,is ok,but in android,15 seconds of video timeout..

Comment: can you show postman request

Comment: I upload the video via "files" in the body

Comment: form-data or binary 
if you used form-data what is key for file ?

Comment: @wadali I use form-data,key of the file "video",I check is correct which I stated it in interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953566/2587027
try this if works without filename

Comment: ok..let me try 1st..then I let u know..ok?

Answer (score 1):

try passing actual file object

```
  file = new File(tasks.getImageUrl());
            requestFile =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
 body =  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);



 sendVideo(body);
```

Comment: this is not what I doing now??What is the different??

Comment: You are passing video as MediaType:
RequestBody videoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), videoFile);
        MultipartBody.Part vFile = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("video", videoFile.getName(), videoBody);

Comment: ah ok..let me try again

Answer (score 1):

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        okhttp3.Request.Builder ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder();
                        ongoing.addHeader("authorization", api_key);
                        return chain.proceed(ongoing.build());
                    }
                })
                // Add below line to your okhttp client
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```