# Unable to upload picture from Android to java server

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, retrofit

I've been trying to implement profile photo upload feature by Android Retrofit + SpringMVC. Java server unable to respond Retrofit API call. Related code snippet is given below:

**ApiInterface**

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/profileImage")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

**uploadToServer**

```
public void uploadToServer(){
    //Get retrofit client
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
    //Get API interface
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    // Get image parts
    MultipartBody.Part imageParts = bitmapToMultipart(imageBitmap);
    //Get image name
    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "ProfileImage");
    //Call image upload API
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(imageParts,name);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

**bitmapToMultipart**

```
public MultipartBody.Part bitmapToMultipart(Bitmap imageBitmap){
    File file = null;
    try {
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        file = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "imageBitmap");
        file.createNewFile();

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);

    return body;
}
```

**Java SpringMVC controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profileImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String imageUploader(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @RequestBody RequestBody name)throws Exception{
        return "";
    }
}
```

**Problem is:** Request not even reaching to java server.

Comment: Your bitmapToMultipart() should `return null;` in that catch block. And where you call that function you should check the return value for null. And not continue if it is null. Please adapt your code.

Comment: Further remove the ByteArrayOutputStream and compress your bitmap to `fos` directly.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that line.

Comment: @greenapps Return type must be `MultipartBody.Part` because which is return type of API parameter. Image can be selected and display in client side, problem is the server no response to the request. I don't think this helps me.

Comment: Yes i see. But it would help you to make your code more robust. And you can return null there even for MultipartBody.Part type. Please add all i asked for.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your optimization advise.☺

Comment: try this library and check once  https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your uploadToServer() function media type should be "multipart/form-data" in place of "text/plain" for field name...

```
//Get image name
    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), "ProfileImage");
```

In your bitmapToMultipart() function media type should be "multipart/form-data". ("image/*" should also work but if not "multipart/form-data" will definitely work)

refer - 
[How to Upload Image file in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2)

And in your spring controller you should use @RequestParam in place of @Requestbody

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profileImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String imageUploader(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @RequestParam String name)throws Exception{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
```

to

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
```

ie you bitmapToMultipart function should be like,

```
public MultipartBody.Part bitmapToMultipart(Bitmap imageBitmap){
    File file = null;
    try {
        //create a file to write bitmap data
        file = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "imageBitmap");
        file.createNewFile();

        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), reqFile);

    return body;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ApiInterface**

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/profileImage")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part("image") MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name") RequestBody name);
```

**uploadToServer**

```
public void uploadToServer(){
    //Get retrofit client
    Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
    //Get API interface
    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    // Get image parts
    MultipartBody.Part imageParts = bitmapToMultipart(imageBitmap);
    //Get image name
    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "ProfileImage");
    //Call image upload API
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.uploadImage(imageParts,name);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            ResponseBody body = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

**bitmapToMultipart**

```
public MultipartBody.Part bitmapToMultipart(Bitmap imageBitmap){

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

    RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), bitmapdata);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", "name", reqFile);

    return body;
}
```

**Java SpringMVC controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profileImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String imageUploader(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile image, @RequestParam String name)throws Exception{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first you should check android client upload file is OK.eg:use compress quality 80

   > imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);
2. change  MediaType and debug at client RequestBody have data
3. Debug at server check receive request data