# Difference between Part and PartMap in Retrofit2 in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, image-uploading

In my application i want **upload** image from phone to **server** with `Retrofit2` . 
For this job i find some sources from internet, but in one source use this :

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/images/upload")
    Call<Response> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
}
```

and in other source this below :

```
public interface ApiConfig {

    @Multipart
    @POST("images/upload_image.php")
    Call<ServerResponse> upload(
            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
}
```

In first source use `@Part MultipartBody.Part image` and in second source use `@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map` .

What's the difference between the two?

Which one do I use better?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2

Comment: @Gokulraj, thanks dear. but my question is what is difference of above codes?

Comment: check this document -https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/PartMap.html

Comment: PartMap did not support several parts with the same name

Comment: @AD10, thanks man. i want just send image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between the two?

`@Part is used during this scenario`,
When you have a multi part request and you know before hand the no of files that needs to be sent to the server you declare it with @part annotation.

`@PartMap is used during this scenario`,
When you don't know the no of parts that has to be sent to the server under the same key we use @PartMap annoation

> Now to answer your question Which one do I use better?

If you have a limites set of images that you have to upload go with @Part approach else use @PartMap.

Comment: Thanks dear friend for your help. i want just upload image and not send any data. **(just image and image name)** . for this can i use this code : `@Part MultipartBody.Part image)` ?

Comment: Thanks dear friend

Comment: glad i could help @Dr.Kong

Answer (score 2):

You can check retrofit 2 document for understanding differences between part & PartMap :

[Differences between Part & PartMap for uploading files](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap)

**Retrofit Documentation:**
If you just need to pass a single or two descriptions with a file, you can just declare it as a @Part in your service .
This works great for small use cases, but if you need to send more than a handful of properties, it gets quite messy, especially if not all of them are always set.

Retrofit offers an easy solution, which makes the uploads quite customizable: @PartMap. @PartMap is an additional annotation for a request parameter, which allows us to specify how many and which parts we send during runtime. This can very helpful if your form is very long, but only a few of those input field values are actually send.

Comment: Thanks dear friend for your help. i want just upload image and not send any data. **(just image and image name)** . for this can i use this code : `@Part MultipartBody.Part image)` ?