# How to upload image file with JSON object in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to upload signature image inside Service Agreement object to the API endpoint. Here is the image of API documentat

[image]

Just for editing of existing Service Agreement I have following Retrofit interface:

```
@PUT("/v3/service_agreement_setups/{id}")
Single<Response<Agreement>> editAgreement(@Path("id") Integer id, @Body AgreementRequest agreementRequest);
```

AgreemnetRequest has the following structure:

public class AgreementRequest {

```
 @Expose @SerializedName("service_agreement_setup") private Agreement  agreement;

public AgreementRequest(Agreement agreement) {
this.agreement = agreement;
}

public Agreement getAgreement() {
return agreement;
}

public void setAgreement(Agreement agreement) {
this.agreement = agreement;
}
}
```

So, as you can see inside Agreement class I should have signature_image field and upload image file.

How I can do that?

Comment: You can use  `@Part MultipartBody.Part` image in `Retrofit`. Just like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2)

Comment: I have tried but MultiPart and Body can not go together.

Comment: Both parts are multipart. The JSON and the image, two parts.

Comment: How then I can set up an image inside JSON object? Can you explain with some code example? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I can comment from 50 xp and above. So I answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)