# Angular / SpringBoot how to send an image file as Request Body?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, http

all the tutorials that i have seen tend to treat an image as a stand alone model and send it using a FormData , what i want is to include the image file as a property of an object Called Course,

what is the process to do so , and in what way should i receive my image in the back-end if it was a property of a model

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by using an @Multipart annotation and getting the image as MultiPartBody.part. You can check in the below link for more detailed explanation.
[How to Upload Image file in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2)