# How to upload File using kotlin coroutines (retrofit)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

How to upload File using kotlin coroutines (retrofit).

Is it possible that i send using syntax similar to this for sending files to server? The current multipart upload seems to be taking a lot of extra code for creating MultipartBody.body and sending to server. Is there any reason for the same ?

Code syntax that i am trying.

```
data class AddCategoryRequest(
    val name: String,
    val image: File?,
    val subCategory: Boolean,
    val parentCategoryId: Int
)

/**
  * Category Create API Call
  */
@POST(Urls.SUB_URL_CREATE_CATEGORY)
suspend fun createCategory(
    @Body createCategoryRequest: AddCategoryRequest
): Category
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-image-file-in-retrofit-2

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm uploading a file in Kotlin with Retrofit + Coroutines:

```
@PUT("")
suspend fun uploadFile(@Url url: String, @Body body: RequestBody)
```

And call it like this:

```
private suspend fun uploadFile(
    localFileEntry: LocalFileEntry,
    file: File
) {
    val requestBody: RequestBody =
        file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    kotlin.runCatching {
        apiInterface.uploadFile(fileUploadInfo.url, requestBody)
    }.onFailure {
        it.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```